# JQ - Merge two arrays

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, jq, array-merge

I'm looking for JQ query that allows me to merge 2 arrays variables (not files) and also take me to overwrite first array with newer value from second array. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

firstArrayVariable='
    [
        {
            "Key": "A B",
            "Value": "1 2"
        },
        {
            "Key": "C D",
            "Value": "3 4"
        },
        {
            "Key": "E F",
            "Value": "5 6"
        },
        {
            "Key": "G H",
            "Value": "9 10"
        }
    ]
'

secondArrayVariable='
    [
        {
            "Key": "A B",
            "Value": "1 2"
        },
        {
            "Key": "C D",
            "Value": "3 4"
        },
        {
            "Key": "G H",
            "Value": "11 12"
        },
        {
            "Key": "J K",
            "Value": "15 16"
        }
    ]
'

jq \
    --compact-output \
    --raw-output \
    --arg jqSecondArrayVariable "${secondArrayVariable}" \
    '. + $jqSecondArrayVariable // empty' \
<<< "${firstArrayVariable}"
```

I could not get it to work and I got following error

> jq: error (at :19): array ([{"Key":"A ...) and string ("\n    [\n ...) cannot be added

**What I expect the result of the merged array is**

```
[
    {
        "Key": "A B",
        "Value": "1 2"
    },
    {
        "Key": "C D",
        "Value": "3 4"
    },
    {
        "Key": "E F",
        "Value": "5 6"
    },
    {
        "Key": "G H",
        "Value": "11 12"
    },
    {
        "Key": "J K",
        "Value": "15 16"
    }
]
```

any helps would be very appreciated!

**UPDATED**

I tried to use `--argjson` as @peak suggested, it concatenate array but it could not merge 2 arrays. Result I got now is an array with duplicated objects

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that 2 input arrays are named as `firstArr` and `secondArr` respectively.

with **`group_by()`** (to group objects by the crucial key `"Key"`) and **`map()`** functions:

```
jq --argjson arr1 "$firstArr" --argjson arr2 "$secondArr" -n \
'$arr1 + $arr2 | group_by(.Key) | map(.[-1])'
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "A B",
    "Value": "1 2"
  },
  {
    "Key": "C D",
    "Value": "3 4"
  },
  {
    "Key": "E F",
    "Value": "5 6"
  },
  {
    "Key": "G H",
    "Value": "11 12"
  },
  {
    "Key": "J K",
    "Value": "15 16"
  }
]
```

---

Alternatively and in such particular case, a faster way, you could apply the following trick with **`unique_by()`** function:

```
jq --argjson arr1 "$firstArr" --argjson arr2 "$secondArr" -n '$arr2 + $arr1 | unique_by(.Key)'
```

Comment: @NamNguyen, welcome, Also, try my second approach (as it's shorter)

Comment: yes, the second approach works PERFECTLY too and even better and shorter. Thanks so much

Comment: What is the purpose of `-n` option? The man page says "Don't read any input at all! Instead, the filter is run once using null as the input. This is useful when using jq as a simple calculator or to construct JSON data from scratch." But I don't quite understand.

Comment: @panc, That means we don't read from standard input or input file in such case, but instead working with global, shell variables (mentioned 2 arrays variables)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `--argjson`; `--arg` interprets its argument as a JSON string. You will also have to modify your jq filter, because simply adding the arrays will result in their concatenation.

For further guidance, see e.g. [Combining JSON by common key-value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296326/combining-json-by-common-key-value-pairs)

Comment: Thanks @peak , I tried `--argjson` , it concatenates 2 arrays but it could not merge them. After my changes, result comes out is a long duplicate objects array `[{"Key":"A B","Value":"1 2"},{"Key":"C D","Value":"3 4"},{"Key":"E F","Value":"5 6"},{"Key":"G H","Value":"9 10"},{"Key":"A B","Value":"1 2"},{"Key":"C D","Value":"3 4"},{"Key":"G H","Value":"11 12"},{"Key":"J K","Value":"15 16"}]`