# jq merge json arrays without duplicates

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I am struggling to merge two JSON arrays with jq, because I would like to remove duplicate keys in merged objects:

**Edit**: added a second key since the example was too simple.

file1.json :

```
[
  {"a": 1, "value": 11},
  {"b": 2},
  {"c": 3}
]
```

file2.json :

```
[
  {"a": 4, "value": 44},
  {"b": 5},
  {"d": 6}
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
  {"a": 4, "value": 44},
  {"b": 5},
  {"c": 3},
  {"d": 6}
]
```

`jq add file1.json file2.json` duplicates the keys (I have two objects with key "a" in the array).

I tried many answers from the web, but everybody has his own use case and none worked directly. The closest is this one: [JQ - Merge two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354926/jq-merge-two-arrays)
but I can't manage to make it work with files instead of string arguments.

My last attempt was

```
jq \
  --slurpfile base file1.json \
  --slurpfile params file2.json \
  '$base + $params | unique_by(.Key)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer has been edited to reflect the change in the Q.]

The following solution uses `INDEX/2` as defined in https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq
One advantage of using `INDEX` is that it avoids using `group_by`, which entails the costs of sorting, which may not be desired in any case.

In case your version of jq does not have `INDEX/2`, here is its definition:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr|
      if type != "string" then tojson
      else .
      end] |= $row);
```

This filter (`INDEX/2`) constructs a dictionary, with keys equal to the distinct values of `idx_expr` applied to elements of the stream,
such that the value associated with a particular key is the *last* item in the stream mapping to that value.

```
[INDEX( add[] | to_entries; (.[0] | .key) )[]
 | from_entries ]
```

Invocation:

```
jq -scf program.jq file1.json file2.json
```

Output:

```
[{"a":4,"value":44},{"b":5},{"c":3},{"d":6}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq --slurpfile file2 file2.json \
'. + $file2[] | map(to_entries) | flatten 
 | group_by(.key) | map(.[-1] | {(.key): .value})' file1.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "a": 4
  },
  {
    "b": 5
  },
  {
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "d": 6
  }
]
```

Comment: While it works with the simplified case I used as an example, as soon as one of the objects has a second key, say `{"a": 1, "t": 10}`, it will create a new object with that key in the result: `[{"a": 1}, {"t": 10}]`.